# Finish a draft in notmuch

Tags: notmuch

I would like to finish a draft in notmuch-emacs email client.

I am just starting with notmuch-emacs. I am able to read, search for, filter emails, send an email. I found notmuch used tag `draft` to work with drafts in usual way , I expect. When I pick up a draft, I am able to forward it, reply to it, but I have not found a way how to open it for editing, finish it and send it. It will be appropriate if the message also lose the tag `draft` in that moment.

If I well understood mu4e, there is a command "resend" binding to "r" that do this job.

I search over the internet, but does not found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem. When viewing the read only draft you can use `M-x` `notmuch-show-resume-message` `RET` which is also bound to `e` in my case.

Comment: Good choice that it is bounded to 'e', as 'edit'. On the other hand, the verb 'show' used in the command name is little bit confusing for me. I was looking for key words as 'draft', 'edit'...

Comment: Indeed, `resume-message` is confusing. (You might have noticed this already, but I believe that the mode that one is in is a prefix to all the interactive functions provided by notmuch.)